# Why there is no output of disassemble command when running it through sourcing script

Tags: tcl

I like to wrap TCL procedure in shell so that I can directly run some TCL routine at BASH. Here is my TCL script file, tools.tcl:

```
  1 proc disassemble {file_name} {
  2     set f [open $file_name r]
  3     set data [read -nonewline $f]
  4     close $f
  5     tcl::unsupported::disassemble script $data
  6 }
  7 
  8 if {$::argc == 0} {
  9     return
 10 }
 11 
 12 [lindex $::argv 0] [lrange $::argv 1 end]
```

I like to run it like this: `tclsh  tools.tcl  disassemble  1.tcl`

But I do not see any output. I added a debug dump, puts $data, just before line 5, it dumps 1.tcl correctly.

Is there a redirection somewhere in tcl::unsupported::disassemble?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
puts [tcl::unsupported::disassemble script $data]
```

The `disassemble` command returns its output as text data. In the console, you can see that directly, but not if it is invoked inside a procedure that is called inside a running script.

Comment: The `disassemble` command was converted from code which wrote directly to standard out from the C level. Which was “fun” when you were running without a real console attached.

Comment: @DonalFellows: consoles are for weenies. Real programmers determine the state of the process by licking the processor's cooling plate.